# Problems with creating a line chart, DateTime as Y and voltage as X

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, charts

I have been tasked to clean up a piece of code that handles the drawing of a chart, this chart will represent changes in voltage[kV] over a period of time. My problem is that as of now, it is working rather poorly, grinding to a halt after a few switches between lables.

You see, there is two radio buttons, they are used to switch the lables on the datapoints, as you go along and switch these back and forth, the application slows down until it stops completly.

I'm lost in the woods here since I'm a novice my self and was not involved with creating this function in the first place, these two factors adding up to a very confused intern.

I think the problem lies in the logic for switching between labels:

```
                var newSerie = new Series();
                var newSerie2 = new Series();

                newSerie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                newSerie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                DataPoint dp = _dataPointList[i]; // FROM
                DataPoint dp2 = _dataPointList2[i]; // TO
                newSerie.Color = Color.Orange;
                newSerie2.Color = Color.MidnightBlue;
                string txt1 = _voltageList[i].Endvalue.ToString();
                string txt2 = _voltageList[i].StartValue.ToString();
                dp.Label = txt2;
                dp2.Label = txt1;
                newSerie.Points.Add(dp);
                newSerie2.Points.Add(dp2);
                newSerie.AxisLabel = _voltageList[i].MyStr;
                newSerie2.AxisLabel = _voltageList[i].MyStr;
                _localChart.Series.Add(newSerie);
                _localChart.Series.Add(newSerie2);
                _localChart.Update();
                newSerie.Points.Remove(dp);
                newSerie2.Points.Remove(dp2);
```

This is then looped through for each individual datapoint in a list.

Comment: Er...there's a lot of code there. Perhaps you could thin it out a bit and reduce it to the essentials.

Comment: @BrianHooper I will do my best to clear out the kludge.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your original post it's clear it needs refactoring. Whoever wrote it originally didn't like to call functions that's for sure!

- Start by refactoring all the stuff that is nothing to do the
  graphing, like calculating the number of seconds in a given month.
  Refactor this stuff in to functions, or even helper classes.
- Then refactor other small bits of functionality out and you will soon
  start to boil this monster of a method down to something more
  manageable and debugable.
- My guess is that the toggle button adds 2 new series, but I can't see
  old series getting removed.

Comment: The original "developer" was a first-timer, so this was kind of expected, but refactoring is probably the way to go.
Would it be to bold to just rewrite the whole function since everything pretty much goes down-hill from here?

Comment: Sometimes that's better. But either way (I presume) it must do what it did before (minus the bugs!). So it's up to you if you want to try to understand what he has done, then recreate it, or refactor as you are interpreting his work. Then once you have refactored, the bugs will standout out, plus there will be no need to rewrite.